# Setting proxy in package.json from .env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package.json

I wish to set `proxy` in package.json from the .env file e.g.

.env:

```
PROXY="https://test.com:1234"
```

package.json:

```
"proxy": $PROXY
```

or however it should be done.

My reasons for doing so is that I don't want to erroneously check in a `package.json` file that has a modified proxy to handle my local development conditions.

I'm under the impression using `dotenv` and `cross-var` only work for commands not simple string setting.

Comment: https://medium.com/@arrayknight/how-to-use-env-variables-in-package-json-509b9b663867

Comment: @CodeSpirit I read that but it really seems to apply to running commands, not a simple environment variable or string. You're effectively running `dotenv` or whatever to provide the command an environment